# How do I find the last sector of harddisk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have not tried to find the last sector by multiplying the number of sectors by 10. I tried to find it by increasing 1 but the system was very tired and took a lot of time. I don't want to filter out the output of ready commands.

How can I find the number of cylinders, heads and sectors. I think I will get the number of sectors by converting from chs system to lba system.

```
import os
def main():
    s=1
    if os.name == "nt":
        while True:
            if read_sector(r"\\.\physicaldrive0",s)=='':
                break
            else:
                s=s*10
            print(s)
    else:
        while True:
            if read_sector("/dev/sda",s)=='':
                break
            else:
                s=s*10
            print(s)
def read_sector(disk, sector_no=0):
    f = open(disk, 'rb')
    f.seek(sector_no * 1)
    read = f.read(1)
    return read

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

or

```
import os
def main():
    s=0
    if os.name == "nt":
        while True:
            if read_sector(r"\\.\physicaldrive0",s)=='':
                break
            else:
                s=s+1
            print(s)
    else:
        while True:
            if read_sector("/dev/sda",s)=='':
                break
            else:
                s=s+1
            print(s)
def read_sector(disk, sector_no=0):
    f = open(disk, 'rb')
    f.seek(sector_no * 1)
    read = f.read(1)
    return read

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def end_sector(disk):
    os.system("fdisk -l %s >fdisk.lst"%disk)
    with open("fdisk.lst") as file:
        dosya=file.read()
        dosya=dosya.split()
        j=0
        for i in dosya:
            j=j+1
        for i in range(j):
            if dosya[i]=="sektör":
                max_sector=int(dosya[i-1])
        for i in range(j):
            if dosya[i]=="=" and dosya[i-1]==dosya[i+1]:
                sector_size=int(dosya[i+1])
    return max_sector,sector_size
dizi=end_sector("/dev/sdb")
print(dizi)
```